# Execution failed for task ':bootRun'. > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to build run a gradle project in CMD. and it shows following error. I tried to change port numbers also, but still same error repeats

Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: what gradle version are you using? @SanthoshKumar

Comment: Please add the full error log , this is not helpful for us , and make sure to add gradle version as well as build.gradle file .

Comment: D:\New folder\Projects\couponservice>javac -version
javac 16.0.1

D:\New folder\Projects\couponservice>gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-08-17 09:59:03 UTC
Revision:     a773786b58bb28710e3dc96c4d1a7063628952ad

Kotlin:       1.5.21
Groovy:       3.0.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          16.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 16.0.1+9-24)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]***********************Web server failed to start. Port 9091 was already in use.

Comment: You have  Access denied error , and for changing the port because its in use ```gradle bootrun --args='--server.port=8888'```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include it and make it easier to read

Comment: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: My not resolved yet, can anyone please help me out